Running nginx on a Raspberry PI, php-fpm fails to install
I have nginx installed Ok with it running using my johnrose.mywire.org server block. When I try to install php-fpm it fails:
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-11-08 09:42:43 GMT; 20ms ago
Docs: man:php-fpm7.4(8)
Process: 3385 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.4
/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)

I have purged php-fpm & php7.4-fpm as well as deleting the directory /etc/php with its contents. But I still get this problem. Any ideas please?
    johnrose.mywire.org server block:
    # Virtual Host configuration for johnrose.mywire.org
    #
    # You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
    # to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
    #
    server {
    
        server_name johnrose.mywire.org;
    
        root /home/manager/www/html;
    
        location / {
        index index.html;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    index index.php;
    root /home/manager/www/php;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location /pictures/ {
        root /home/manager/www;
    }
 
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/johnrose.mywire.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/johnrose.mywire.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = johnrose.mywire.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name johnrose.mywire.org;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


what OS on the rpi, and could you sgare your server block?

@Journeyman Geek According to 'sudo apt update' OS is Debian Bullseye. Windows Manager is lxde. johnrose.mywire.org server block is:
server {
server_name johnrose.mywire.org;
root /home/manager/www/html;
location / {
index index.html;
}
location ~ .php$ {
index index.php;
root /home/manager/www/php;
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
location /pictures/ {
root /home/manager/www;
PS cannot include all of server block due to it then exceeding max comment size: rest of comment is certbot  inserted lines.

Put it in the question please

@Journeyman Geek server block now in question.

@Journeyman Geek Just wondered if the problem might be due to the php location lines in the server block? I've now deleted them but still same result.
